# Changing an async/await function that checks for an element on the page to work with Safari 10

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following function, it checks whether the element specified by `selector` is on the page.

This code runs when the page loads, before the element has loaded. So it will continue to try and find the element until the maximum `timeout` is reached, and then `return false`

```
function rafAsync() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
  });
}

export default async function checkElement(timeout = 20) {
  let counter = 0;
  while (document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    if (counter > timeout) return false;
    await rafAsync();
  }
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```

The problem is that I need to support Safari 10 and some other browsers which do not work with `async/await`.

How can I make this work without needing the `await` but still returning the element if it is found?

The call for the `checkElement` function is as follows:

lookForElement() {

```
this.checkElement(selectorTimeout).then(element => {
  this.element = element;
  if (!this.element) {
    debug("Sorry, we couldn't find your element");
    return;
  }
  // ...continue
});
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to transpile from ES2017 to ES2015 or ES5 via a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) or [Traceur](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler).

If you want to do this manually, as you can see from [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), `async` functions are syntactic sugar for promise creation and consumption. An `async` function returns a promise. It starts with a bit of synchronous code, and then returns the promise as of the first `await` or `return` encountered in the program flow.

That function is quite simple and so is easily rewritten:

```
export default function checkElement(timeout = 20) {
  // Create and return our promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Initialize counter and do first check
    let counter = 0;
    check();

    function check() {
      // Got the element?
      let element = document.querySelector(selector);
      if (element != null) {
        // Yes, resolve the promise
        resolve(element);
      } else {
        // No, timeout?
        counter = counter + 1; // ++counter; or counter++; would be more idiomatic
        if (counter > timeout) {
          // Yes
          resolve(false); // rejecting here would be more idiomatic, but that's not what your `async` function did
        } else {
          // No, check again on next RAF
          rafAsync().then(check);
        }
    }
  });
}
```